# Windows 8 embedded tiny touch keyboard

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, touchscreen

I have a Windows 8 embedded system with a portrait screen orientation. The touch keyboard is so tiny that I hardly see letters on it. Microsoft documentation says that touch keyboard size depends on screen resolution, but I don't have ultra high resolution also.

Any tips on how to fix this would be appreciated.
Photo of the screen:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried "Make text and other things larger or smaller"?

Comment: Yes, I'd tried it. Does not change the size of keyboard.